# Pytest parametrize with dynamic values

Tags: pytest, parametrized-testing

I would like to run test several times according to given list.
I build the list according to a given file at the 'setup_module' section.
Is it possible to do something like this?

```
data = []

def setup_module(module):
    with open('data.json') as config_file:
        configData = json.load(config_file)
    data = fillData(configData)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("data", data)
def test_data(data):
    for d in data:
        .
        .
        .
```

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: The correct answer here depends crucially on a detail not mentioned in the question:  do you need to prevent loading the file "data.json" at import time (i.e. during the test discovery stage), or is that OK?

Comment: You can totally do that as long as data variable is an iterable.

Comment: @wim it doesn't have to be during test discovery stage

Comment: @SilentGuy data is a list of objects. The problem is that data in the parametrize initialize before setup_module - data in test_data function is empty

Comment: @AviElgal You didn't really answer my question - is it OK to load "data.json" during test discovery?

Comment: @wim Yes it's OK

Comment: In that case just delete the `setup_module` function, you don't need it.  Load the data from file at the module scope.

Comment: This What I did, I thought I can do it with setup_module as well. Thanks.

Comment: Use data as pytest attribute to make it available at the time of parametrization. 

```
def setup_module(module):
    with open('data.json') as config_file:
        configData = json.load(config_file)
    pytest.data = fillData(configData)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("data", pytest.data)
def test_data(data):
    for d in data:
```

And, please don't reuse variable names.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about format of your data. you could do like this

```
  import pytest
  scenarios = [('first', {'attribute': 'value'}), ('second', {'attribute': 'value'})]

  @pytest.mark.parametrize("test_id,scenario",scenarios)
  def test_scenarios(test_id,scenario):
           assert scenario["attribute"] == "value"
```